# pipコマンドでPython2、pip3コマンドでPython3が使われるようにしたい

Tags: python, macos

自分のpipは以下に入っているのですが、

```
$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip
```

多分ここにpipが入っているせいで  `requests` などをpipでインストールしても、python2.7.6で使えない状態になってます。どうやったら解決できるのでしょうか。何卒お知恵をお貸しください。

`python` と `pip` でpython 2.7.6を、`python3` と `pip3` でpython 3.4.3を使えるようにしたいです。
よろしく御願い致します。

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3

$ which easy_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/easy_install

$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip

$ which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3
```

Comment: 読みやすいように文章とタイトルを修正しました。もし問題がありましたら、お手数ですが[edit]をお願いします。

Comment: 現状の`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip`を削除するか、名前変更して、python用のpipが見つかるのでは？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSとPythonをインストールした方法（Python公式のインストーラを使ったのか、Homebrewなどのツールを使ったのか）は書いていただけると回答しやすいと思います。

以下、Python3はPython公式のインストーラでインストールした（この方法→[4. Macintosh で Python を使う — Python 3.3.6 ドキュメント](http://docs.python.jp/3.3/using/mac.html)）もので、Python2は自分ではインストールしていない、と考えて回答します。違いましたら無視してください。

まず、Python 2.7用の pip はインストールされているのでしょうか？今は OS 標準でインストールされている Python2 を使っているようですが、このバージョンには標準では pip は付属していません。別途インストールが必要です。

もしまだ pip をインストールしていないようでしたら、pip と一緒に Python2 も Python3 同様にシステムとは別にインストールすることをおすすめします。理由は公式ドキュメント（[Macintosh で Python を使う — Python 2.7ja1 documentation](http://docs.python.jp/2.7/using/mac.html)）にもあるように、OS に予期せぬ影響を与えないためです。

> Apple が提供している Python は /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework と /usr/bin/python にそれぞれインストールされています。これらは Apple が管理しているものであり Apple やサードパーティのソフトウェアが使用するので、編集したり削除してはいけません。

システムとは別に Python2 と pip をインストールするには、公式から配布されている Python2.7.9 のパッケージを使うのが簡単だと思います。pip のインストールやパスの設定も自動でやってもらえます。

[Macintosh で Python を使う — Python 2.7ja1 documentation](http://docs.python.jp/2.7/using/mac.html)

特に理由がなければこの方法でいいと思います。記述されているバージョンは古いですが、インストール方法に違いはなさそうです。Homebrewなどを使いたい場合はそれでもいいと思いますが、最終的に Python3 と同じ方法でインストールされている方が後々管理しやすいと思います。

どうしてもシステムのPythonを使いたい場合、あるいはすでに pip をインストールしていてそれを使いたい場合、その pip のパスが python3 の pip より先に来るようにシェルの設定ファイルで PATH を設定するか、エイリアスを設定（ `alias pip=/path/to/pip`）してしまえばいいのではないでしょうか。仮想環境での利用を考えると、PATH を設定したほうがいいと思います。

既存の Python に pip をインストールする方法は [Python - いつの間にかpipのインストールが楽になってた件 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/who_you_me/items/831d62f396e6d66dda66) などが参考になります。おそらくワンライナーの最後の `python` の前に `sudo` が必要です。

Answer (score 0):

ほとんど Python を使わないのですが予備用として pyenv でインストールしています。
当方ではご希望のような `python2` / `python3` の使い分けが出来ているので、その環境の作り方を簡単にご案内します。

- [yyuu/pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)

pyenv 自体は `git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv` で入りますし、 Homebrew を使っているならば `brew install pyenv` でもインストール出来ます。

pyenv インストールが終わったら、`.bash_profile` への[設定](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#installation) を行います（詳細はリンク先を確認してください）。
引き続いて Python の各バージョンの（最新のものを）インストールをします。もちろんご希望の2.7.6を指定してもかまいませんが。

```
$ pyenv install 2.7.9
$ pyenv install 3.4.3
```

インストールされているバージョンを確認します。

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/riocampos/.pyenv/version)
  2.7.9
  3.4.3
```

おまたせしました。ご希望の環境を設定します。

```
$ pyenv global 2.7.9 3.4.3

$ pyenv versions
  system (set by /Users/riocampos/.pyenv/version)
* 2.7.9
* 3.4.3
```

`pyenv global` 直後に指定したバージョンが `python` コマンドでのデフォルトバージョンになります。
なお Homebrew では `python` コマンドで動作するバージョンが Python 2系であると決め打ちしているものがあるので、2系と3系、という順序にしておくのが無難です（[homebrewを使うならばpyenvでは必ずPython2を一つ目に設定すること（もしくはPython3を優先したMacでのRicty作成苦労話） - 別館 子子子子子子（ねこのここねこ）](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/riocampos+tech/20140406/pyenv_must_be_set_python2_as_python)）。

では設定状況を確認してみましょう。

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.9
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.3

$ pip --version
pip 6.1.1 from /Users/riocampos/.pyenv/versions/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip2 --version
pip 6.1.1 from /Users/riocampos/.pyenv/versions/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip3 --version
pip 6.0.8 from /Users/riocampos/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

これでご希望の使い分けが可能です。ホームディレクトリ以下にインストールされているので `sudo` も不要です。

お役に立ちますことを願っております。